# Open a Word File from Javascript Similar to Clicking a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink in my web page that opens a Word document however before the document is open I need to perform some other tasks.  I substituted the hyperlink for a button and this successfully runs my code but how can I then open the Word document in a browser agnostic fashion, i.e. similar to the anchor element;

```html
<a href="file:///\\MyServer\MonthlyReport\Monthly Progress Report.docm">Produce Report</a>
```

I have tried several searches for this problem but most of the responses suggest using something like "window.location" top open the file but I don't want to load the file in the browser.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using `window.location` would cause the browser to still download the file once the browser determines the type of file is a Word document. Is there something else you wanted it to do? Does that not work?

Comment: There is no way you would be able to launch an application on the user's machine from javascript without some sort of plugin. Imagine if this were possible, this would be a huge security issue (a malicious website, for example, could download a virus and use javascript to run the virus and infect the machine).

Comment: @KJPrice I have tried several variations using `window.location` but the closest I have come is `window.location = file:///Shared Files/Monthly Progress Report - AutoOpen.docm` to which I get the error *Not allowed to load local resource* displayed in the console.

Comment: @JohnBergman - I'm not attempting to run an application on the user's machine, I'm attempting to open a document in the same way you can open a Word document from a hyperlink.

Comment: That message is because it is a local file. Try a file accessible using http. Something found online or on your localhost if you have one setup.